# The function nchar is not supported with natively compiled modules

Tags: sql-server, function, memory-optimized-tables

> Error : The function nchar is not supported with natively compiled modules.

How I can use `Nchar()` Function in native Function?

my query is :

```
Declare @Input NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Output NVARCHAR(MAX)=N''
DECLARE @i INT
DECLARE @C NVARCHAR(1)

SET @i=0
SET @C=SUBSTRING(@Input,@i,1)

While  @C Not IN (
        NCHAR(0x060C), -- Arabic Comma
        NCHAR(0x061B) -- Arabic Semicolon
        )
Begin 
    SET @Output=@Output+@C
End
```

Comment: Use non-native function

Comment: Are you not able to supply these as string literals? E.g. `N'،',N'؛'`?

Comment: Or cast @C to BINARY(2) and compare to 0x060C.  That will be a simple binary (non-collation-sensitive) comparison.